# Set binding in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to rotate a cube with a binding in code behind.

I tried a few things but at this moments,not working...

I attached the source code,xaml and c#

code xaml:

```
    <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown_1" >
    <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="6 5 4" LookDirection="-6 -5 -4">
            </PerspectiveCamera>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight x:Name="dirLightMain" Direction="-1,-1,-1">
                </DirectionalLight>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                            Positions="0 0 0  1 0 0  0 1 0  1 1 0  0 0 1  1 0 1  0 1 1  1 1 1"
                            TriangleIndices="2 3 1  2 1 0  7 1 3  7 5 1  6 5 7  6 4 5  6 2 0  2 0 4  2 7 3  2 6 7  0 1 5  0 5 4">
                        </MeshGeometry3D>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain">
                            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                        </DiffuseMaterial>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate" Axis="0 1 0"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>

        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="360" Orientation="Horizontal"
Value="{Binding ElementName=rotate, Path=Angle}" ></Slider>

    </Grid>
```

code c#:

```
 private void Grid_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding { 
            Source=rotate,
            Path=new PropertyPath("Angle")
            };


        }

    }
```

Binding of the slider working corect, I want when press "S" to rotate the cube

Comment: I dont think you understand the concept of binding. your VM should contain a proerpty Rotation and your key down events should modify that. When you have Bindings, you do not have Code Behind.

Comment: I think you're right

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dependency Property in your code behind like this

```
public double Angle
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

And then bind rotation to that instead.

Then in your key handler, you can increment Angle, something like this:

```
Angle = (Angle + 1.0) % 360.0
```